# Is there a way to properly synchronize audio video in python?

Tags: python, audio, video, synchronization

I am trying to do audio with video automation in Python. I want to synchronize a audio file with video. currently I am using $ to split it into parts wherever there are pause. Is there any other way to do it??.below is code

```
    # Split the text into parts based on consecutive dollar signs ('$')
    text_parts = text.split('$')

    # Initialize a list to store translated and speech-generated audio segments
    audio_segments = []

    # Iterate through text parts
    for part in text_parts:
        stripped_part = part.strip()
        if stripped_part:
            # Translate each part
            translated_part = self.translate_text(stripped_part, target_language)

            # Generate speech for the translated part
            tts = gTTS(translated_part, lang=target_language, slow=False)
            tts.save("temp_part.mp3")
            audio_segment = AudioSegment.from_file("temp_part.mp3")
            audio_segments.append(audio_segment)

    # Calculate pause duration based on the number of consecutive dollar signs
    print(text_parts)
    pause_duration = 500 * len(text_parts)

    # Create silence for the calculated pause duration
    silence = AudioSegment.silent(duration=pause_duration)

    # Combine audio segments with silence to create the final audio
    final_audio = audio_segments[0]
    for segment in audio_segments[1:]:
        final_audio += silence + segment

    # Export the final audio with pauses
    final_audio.export("output_with_pauses.mp3", format="mp3")

    # Generate the video with translated speech
    self.generate_video_with_speech(self.translate_text(text, target_language), target_language)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need [GStreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/).GStreamer is an extremely powerful and versatile framework for creating streaming media applications. Also can help you pass a media file or media stream from one device to another device.
GStreamer provides various components which help you build your own pipeline. For example, to sync synchronize a audio file, just execute:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/path/to/your/file.mp3 ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! lamemp3enc target=bitrate bitrate=192 ! rtpmpapay ! udpsink host=targetIP port=5000
```

and another machine

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! "application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)MPA" ! rtpmpadepay ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! filesink location=/path/to/save/received/file.mp3
```